# Difference between 'I love you' and 'I have loved you'

Tags: grammar, phrase-meaning

What is the difference between below phrases.

1. I love you
2. I have loved you

Comment: What does your grammar book say?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

'I have/'ve loved you' needs a time marker => e.g. I've **always** loved you. *or* I've loved you **for ages**. *or* I've loved you **since we first met**.

'I love you' doesn't need any time marker.

Comment: Probably the best 'explanation' (there's almost always an underlying _why?_) I've ever seen. 
 I'll just add a further, perfective,  example: 'I _have_ loved you in the past, but what you did has soured our relationship'. // I'm torn; I very rarely upvote answers to questions that belong on say ELL.